# not able to get response from deployed package

Tags: oracle, soap, plsql, soa

I had created a plsql package and uploaded it to integrated SOA gateway. I generated WSDL and deployed the service. But when i am testing the service by calling it using soap ui , the response  coming back is empty as given below.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body/>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now I tried calling the procedure in the package from another block and found that the data is coming properly there.

But when I searched in SOA monitor and found that the status of the request received is "success" and the response is empty.

My package specification is as follows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE XX_FS_ALL_TASKS_PUB AS
/* $Header: $ */
/*#
* This package is the public interface for Dynamic Field Service Tasks Data.
* @rep:scope public
* @rep:product csf
* @rep:displayname XX_FS_ALL_TASKS_PUB
* @rep:lifecycle active
* @rep:compatibility S
* @rep:category BUSINESS_ENTITY CSF_TASK_DEBRIEF
*/
    /*#
    * Use this procedure to get dynamic Field Service details
    * @param p_assignee_id  Assignee id
    * @param x_task_rec Task details
    * @param x_return_code  Error Code details
    * @rep:displayname get_tasklist
    */
    PROCEDURE get_tasklist (
        p_assignee_id IN  NUMBER,
        x_task_rec    OUT xx_fs_mob_loc_rec.all_task_tab,
        x_return_code OUT VARCHAR2
    );
END XX_FS_ALL_TASKS_PUB;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a function, not procedure, something like this

```
/*#
* Use this procedure to get dynamic Field Service details
* @param p_assignee_id  Assignee id
* @return Status
* @rep:displayname get_tasklist
* @rep:scope public
* @rep:category BUSINESS_ENTITY CSF_TASK_DEBRIEF
*/
FUNCTION get_tasklist (

  p_assignee_id          IN       NUMBER,

) return x_result;
```

and x_result should be a custom object which contains the data you are returning.

Comment: Kadir : Still same error response from EBS. It will not give me any valid response. Always an empty response from EBS SOA gateway. But when we check the package in my TOAD it give me some valid response

Comment: I think you should add scope and category annotation to your method also, can you try like that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **IrepOverloadSeq** tag in the generated xml file of the package you deployed(procedure_name.xml) in the **PLSQL** folder of your EBS instance, which comes under the **SOA** folder. Save the file and test again.